# WinSCP vs. CoreFTP and not being to see files

Tags: ftp, winscp, directory-listing

I'm using FTP protocol on port 21 (not SFTP or anything else).

Using Core FTP LE, I connect to the server in question and I can see all the files in the directories

Using WinSCP, I can connect to the server and I can see the folders; however, files are not listed.

Any idea what the problem could be? It can't be a security issue, given I can see the files using Core FTP.

Comment: Can you share a log file from both clients?

Comment: I guess the problem had to do with the version of winSCP (4.2.7); after the upgrade to 5.5.1 the files are now showing up... not sure what the down-vote was all about though.

Comment: It's likely due to WinSCP 4.2.7 using `LIST` command, while 5.5.1 using `MLSD` command. Either your server is buggy and does not show files in `LIST` output or its listing format is not recognized by WinSCP.

Comment: Regarding the vote down: I suppose the voter reflected absolute lack of any information in your post that may help answering the question.

Comment: Also your question is out of topic for stackoverflow.com. It should go to superuser.com.

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for the explanation; our counterparts did mention their other clients who used older versions of winscp had some problems as well. So I think there maybe some server side issues; I'm using powershell to upload our files; we do an "ls" before and after the upload (they cleanup the folder quite regularly) to ensure our file is loaded, and also we read the logs to get more info on the uploaded file (filesize, name, etc...); after their server upgrade, our LS failed to work; hence the question; anyways, i'll try to include more info on my future questions (logs etc) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had to do with the version of WinSCP (4.2.7); after the upgrade to 5.5.1 I can now browse through the files.

Comment: This issue still exists in 2020 with version 5.17.7. Not sure how it happened, but we have a file with just the extension e.g. ".csv" WinSCP is not able to see it.